# L2TP/IPSec VPN setup Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: vpn

I am trying to setup a VPN server in Microsoft Azure to use for private/secure browsing. I found many tutorials on how to setup L2TP/IPSec on Windows Server and I was able to set it up and connect to it. However, I think I am missing a few steps to make client internet traffic go through the VPN server.

All the tutorials I found are work-related VPNs so they're not mentioning those extra steps. I think it has something to do with enabling NAT but I am not exactly sure what to do.

If anyone can provide any tutorials or give me guides/hints on what to do for setting up L2TP/IPSec on Windows (or linux) for the purpose of private/secure browsing would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclosure: I am the author of this GitHub repository.

Please see [Setup IPsec VPN](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn) for a "one-click" IPsec VPN server setup script intended for use on Ubuntu, Debian or CentOS, for the purpose of private/secure browsing. Additionally, you may refer to [Deploy to Microsoft Azure](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/azure/README.md) as well as [Configure IPsec/L2TP VPN Clients](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md) from the same repository.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out tomorrow and report back here.